# Restcomm smsc gateway: How to forward incoming messages

Tags: smpp, restcomm, jsmpp

I am using restcomm smsc gateway 7.3.135.  I need to achieve the following.

1. SmppClient --> RestcommSMSC ---> ExternalSMPPServer
2. SmppClient --> RestcommSMSC ---> ExternalHTTPServer

Can you please help how to achieve this type of routing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same requirements. From the documentation, the default is to have HTTP only for incoming sendSMS requests.

https://www.restcomm.com/docs/core/smsc/SMSC_Gateway_Admin_Guide.html#_design_overview

You will notice that HTTP have only one direction.

For this requirement you have two options:

1. Configure routing/processing classes to do this job. But flexibility will be an issue here.
2. Use other tools like JasminSMPP to do this job. The issue here is the scalability of TPS of the JasminSMPP. Configuring jasminsmpp is pretty easy to be done and it does the job of SMPP to HTTP fine.

If you came across another solution please share.

Thanks.

Comment: Sure you can use Docker with jasmin to enhance the scalability